# Cannot call my C# ASP.NET Core 7 controller from Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I created a new project using one of Visual Studio templates (ASP.NET Core with Angular). I created a new controller called `ContactController`. Within the controller, I created a `GET` method called `TestSaveContact`.

For some reason I cannot hit the method from Postman. What am I doing wrong?

[POSTMAN CALL Screen Shot]
[image]

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PersonalWebsite2023.Models;
using PersonalWebsite2023.Services.Interfaces;

namespace PersonalWebsite2023.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ContactController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("TestSaveContact")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> TestSaveContact()
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, new { msg = ex.Message });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: RESTly nit picking: a method that is supposed to *save* data should **NOT** be a `GET` method - use a `POST` for creating new data, `PUT` or `PATCH` for updating. `GET` should **only** be used for methods that retrieve / fetch / return data - but **NOT** for methods to **modify** data in any way, shape or form ....

Comment: add api word before like https://localhost:44467/apí/Contact/TestSaveContact

Comment: What does your Program.cs / Startup.cs file look like? Do you do anything special with routing, controllers, etc?

Comment: @CarlosCocom I tried this and it still didn't work.

Comment: @gunr2171 I didn't do anything special with routing. I edit my main post to include my Program.cs.

Comment: Remove the [Route["[controller]")] from the class. The default name is derived from the class name minus Controller, so this will result in a route value of "Contact" which matches the url in the screenshot.

Comment: I created a blank .net core 7 project, pasted all the above code in to VS and ran it without issue. I dont think its a code thing. Go to your projects properties -> debug -> general and open the debug lanuch profiles. Make sure your port is correct. It should be https://localhost:44467 based on the Postman screennshot. I am thinking that maybe you are running two different debug sessions and the postman is pointing to the other application.

Comment: You need to call on AddControllers (not with views as you seem to be running an API project) and MapControllers (within UseEndpoints), that should make it work. I also suggest you follow the advice provided in Tequipo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing both MVC and Web API bits and pieces - can you try to change your `program.cs` to be just like this (this is basically the VS 2022 standard for an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API - just API, no MVC):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// just use .AddControllers() - that's enough for Web API - no need for views
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// not sure if you want this - typically, you want to secure a Web API
app.UseAuthorization();

// MapControllers handles all that is needed for default Web API behaviour
app.MapControllers();

/* no need for static files, or explicit routing ....
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
*/

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `[Route("TestSaveContact")]` and change `HttpGet` attribute to `[HttpGet("TestSaveContact")]`.

Comment: Hello, I tried this and the same error occurs.